# Asterisk use of Log vs NoOp

Tags: asterisk

In all the conversations I read, none ever named the possibility to use the function Log in the extensions.conf

Then I found this minimal description:
https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Log

What are the downsides of using Log vs NoOp, or using a shell to log some message?

Answer (score 0):

You can use anyone. There is also Verbose with same functionality

Noop do NOTHING, i.e it not change verbose level, just output to console or to log which marked as "all" in logger.conf

Verbose allow control log level, so you can setup in logger file for different levels.

Log do same as verbose, but level is STRING not integer.